# Texture filtering: Is the minification or the magnification filter used when rendering at the exact texture size?

Tags: textures, graphics

Suppose you have a texture where the minification filter is linear, but the magnification filter is nearest-neighbor (point filtering). If the texture is rendered at exactly 1:1 pixels, but at a non-whole-number pixel position, it is being neither minified or magnified.

Is there a convention for whether the min or mag filter will be used? What is the justification?

Answer (score 3):

The OpenGL documentation specifies that OpenGL uses the magnification filter.

> The texture magnification function is used when the pixel being textured maps to an area less than or equal to one texture element.

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml

I couldn't find any such documentation for Direct3D so if someone can confirm the D3D behavior it would be helpful.

Comment: That is a fun bit of trivia!